# how to make a checkout progress bar on a web page accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility

By a checkout progress bar, I mean something like this:

[image: a checkout progress bar example]

I am trying to make such web ui component accessible, especially for screen reader(like JAWS) users. I have been googling for hours to find some aria attributes that are designed for such use case, but didn't find any.

A not so elegant solution that I can think about is that, whenever this progress bar changes -- advance or going back, use javascript to generate an alert message in a format like "you completed:abc, you are now at:d, you still have:efg to go". I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: You could use the progressbar role and ARIA tags to achieve this. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_progressbar_role)

Answer (score 2):

A horizontal timeline can easily be setup with bootstrap 3 and inline lists like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Which will result (with styling) to appear like this: [image]

See codepen: 
http://codepen.io/richfergus/pen/pNvRWd?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5's progress tag and ARIA's progressbar role.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_progressbar_role